# Scheduled Database Updates on Given Date - MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a requirement where I need to Update some fields in database on monthly basis, I know I can use Cron Jobs, But I don't have access to use Cron, So is there any other way doing this in PHP, MySQL, JQuery or any other ??

I just need to update & Insert some rows in Database Tables on the scheduled time Automatically.

Comment: Ask for Access OR manually run the script each month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have site or something else with regular visits you can check with each visit is it time to run you job or not. If I not mistake wordpress's jobs are working in this way.

Comment: I was thinking of this, Coz I'm working on OSTicket, It uses the same thing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever heard of MySQL Event Scheduler?

[Info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

[Creating event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Do you have access to it? If you want to check whether event_scheduler is running you can type `show processlist` - there should be a process run by User 'event_scheduler'. If not you can always run it.

Of course the best way is to add `event_scheduler = ON` in mysql config file (in `mysqld` section).